# How can I refer an action button to an inserted plot (insertUI/removeUI) in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have asked [this question in the RStudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dynamically-removing-ui-elements-using-insertui-and-removeui/22617) and didn't get help, so I try it here:

I am trying to add the following functionality to my app: When the user inserts a plot, a remove button should appear that specifically removes the plot that was inserted at the same time. The app is based on insertUI and removeUI.

This would be the example app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Example data

a<-(letters)
b<-rnorm(length(letters), 4,2)
c<-rnorm(length(letters), 10,15)
d<-c(1:10,20:30,45:49)

data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
names(data)<-c("name","v1","v2","v3")

# UI

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("add", "Add"),
    radioButtons("add_elements","", c("Element1",   "Element2"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow( tags$div(id="placeholder")
    )
))

# Server Logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {

 # Initialize empty vector
  inserted<- c()

  # Observer
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id_add <- paste0(input$add, input$add_elements)

    insertUI(selector = '#placeholder', where = "afterEnd",
             ui= switch(input$add_elements,
                        'Element1'= plotOutput(id_add),
                        'Element2' = plotOutput(id_add))
    )

    output[[id_add]] <- 
      if (input$add_elements == "Element1") 

        renderPlot({
          plot(data[,1],data[,2])

          }) else if (input$add_elements == "Element2") 

          renderPlot({
            plot(data[,1],data[,4])
            })
    inserted <<- c(id_add,inserted)
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = tags$div(actionButton("remove_button", "Remove"))
      )})

  ## Remove Elements ###
  observeEvent(input$remove_button, {
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When a plot is inserted, it gets an ID, such as 1Element1 or 2Element2. I am now wondering how could a remove button only refer to a plot with this exact ID?

So far, I have worked with a single remove button that removes the last inserted plot by defining a vector that stores the IDs.

```
selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
```

This is not very useful when a user needs to compare many plots. I have a limited understanding in using these selectors and absolutely no idea how could incorporate a remove button for every plot that only removes the respective plot. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Also, [this link](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/barbara/insertUI/) may help since it shows a similar functionality (that I was obviously not able to implement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of situation I always use 'list' with 'reactiveValues' like below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Example data

a<-(letters)
b<-rnorm(length(letters), 4,2)
c<-rnorm(length(letters), 10,15)
d<-c(1:10,20:30,45:49)

data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
names(data)<-c("name","v1","v2","v3")

# UI

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("add", "Add"),
    radioButtons("add_elements","", c("Element1",   "Element2"))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("myUI")
  ))

# Server Logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  alld <- reactiveValues()
  alld$ui <- list()

  output$myUI <- renderUI({
    alld$ui
  })

  # Observer
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id_add <- length(alld$ui)+1

    alld$ui[[id_add]] <-  list(
      plotOutput(paste0("plt",id_add)),
      actionButton(paste0("remove_button", id_add), "Remove")
    )


      if (input$add_elements == "Element1"){
        output[[paste0("plt",id_add)]] <- renderPlot(plot(data[,1],data[,2]))
      } else {
        output[[paste0("plt",id_add)]] <- renderPlot(plot(data[,1],data[,4]))
      }
    })



  ## Remove Elements (for all plots) ###
observe({
  lapply(seq_len(length(alld$ui)), function(i){
    id_add <- i
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("remove_button", id_add)]], {
      alld$ui[[id_add]][1] <- NULL
    })
  })

})


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution (and sorry for not getting back to you for a week). The use of `reactiveValues` and `list()` is indeed very nice. I am trying to understand a few things: What exactly does the `ouput[["expression"]] <- renderPlot{...}` do? Does this add a value to a list?