# Shiny app: delete UI objects with action buttons

Tags: r, shiny

With the following code, it is possible to create UI objects in Shiny.

```
library(shiny)


LHSchoices <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE UI ----
variablesUI <- function(id, number) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             selectInput(ns("variable"),
                         paste0("Select Variable ", number),
                         choices = c("Choose" = "", LHSchoices)
             )
      ),

      column(6,
             numericInput(ns("value.variable"),
                          label = paste0("Value ", number),
                          value = 0, min = 0
             )
      )
    )
  )

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE SERVER ----

variables <- function(input, output, session, variable.number){
  reactive({

    req(input$variable, input$value.variable)

    # Create Pair: variable and its value
    df <- data.frame(
      "variable.number" = variable.number,
      "variable" = input$variable,
      "value" = input$value.variable,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    return(df)

  })
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Shiny UI ----

ui <- fixedPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),
  variablesUI("var1", 1),
  h5(""),
  actionButton("insertBtn", "Add another line")

)

# Shiny Server ----

server <- function(input, output) {

  add.variable <- reactiveValues()

  add.variable$df <- data.frame("variable.number" = numeric(0),
                                "variable" = character(0),
                                "value" = numeric(0),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  var1 <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", 1), 1)

  observe(add.variable$df[1, ] <- var1())

  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {

    btn <- sum(input$insertBtn, 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = "h5",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tagList(
        variablesUI(paste0("var", btn), btn)
      )
    )

    newline <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", btn), btn)

    observeEvent(newline(), {
      add.variable$df[btn, ] <- newline()
    })

  })

  output$test1 <- renderPrint({
    print(add.variable$df)
  })

  output$test2 <- renderTable({
    add.variable$df
  })

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, I would like to add a button for each row to delete it if we click on it.

[image]

First I don't quite understand how the `variables` function works: inside the function, we can see that `input$variable` is used, but how does it know which `selectInput` is used? I think that I don't understand how `ns("variable")` works.

So now, it is difficult to create remove buttons. I am trying: 
I used [this link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/removeUI.html) to create a remove button, but I don't know how to make each button work.

```
library(shiny)


LHSchoices <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")

LHSchoices2 <- c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE UI ----
variablesUI <- function(id, number) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             selectInput(ns("variable"),
                         paste0("Select Variable ", number),
                         choices = c("Choose" = "", LHSchoices)
             )
      ),

      column(3,
             numericInput(ns("value.variable"),
                          label = paste0("Value ", number),
                          value = 0, min = 0
             )
      ),
      column(3,
             actionButton(ns("rmvv"),"Remove UI")
      ),
    )
  )

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE SERVER ----

variables <- function(input, output, session, variable.number){
  reactive({

    req(input$variable, input$value.variable)

    # Create Pair: variable and its value
    df <- data.frame(
      "variable.number" = variable.number,
      "variable" = input$variable,
      "value" = input$value.variable,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    return(df)

  })
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Shiny UI ----

ui <- fixedPage(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",id="tabs",
              tabPanel("t1",value="t1"),
              tabPanel("t2",value="t2")),

  variablesUI("var1", 1),
  h5(""),
  actionButton("insertBtn", "Add another line"),

  verbatimTextOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),

  actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
  textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful")
)

# Shiny Server ----

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # this remove button works, from https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/removeUI.html
  observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(> #txt)"
    )
  })

  # trying to make the following work
  observeEvent(input$rmvv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "h5"
    )
  })


  add.variable <- reactiveValues()

  add.variable$df <- data.frame("variable.number" = numeric(0),
                                "variable" = character(0),
                                "value" = numeric(0),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  var1 <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", 1), 1)

  observe(add.variable$df[1, ] <- var1())

  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {

    btn <- sum(input$insertBtn, 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = "h5",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tagList(
        variablesUI(paste0("var", btn), btn)
      )
    )

    newline <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", btn), btn)

    observeEvent(newline(), {
      add.variable$df[btn, ] <- newline()
    })

  })

  output$test1 <- renderPrint({
    print(add.variable$df)
  })

  output$test2 <- renderTable({
    add.variable$df
  })

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @DuncanEllis, I think you've done this before, haven't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be multiple ways to do this. One is suggested in the docu of `removeUI()`: To wrap your addded ui part in a div with an id.

Then your selector would be fairly easy to add:

```
removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#var", btn)
)
```

, where `#` is the identifier for ids in jquery´s selectors.

Next, you would have to add multiple observe events. It might be surprising, but that this can actually be done from within other reactive contexts. So it might be the easiest way to add this listener when you create the new ui.
So within `observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {...})` you can add:

```
observeEvent(input[[paste0("var", btn,"-rmvv")]], {
  removeUI(
    selector = paste0("#var", btn)
  )
})
```

Then you have as many listeners as you have (newly added) ui components.

**Potential enhancements:**

- The initially added ui.

Since you added one row manually, the corresponding listener would have to be added manually as well. In order to keep the code not too long i didnt add this part, but i am happy to edit.

- Counting the amount of rows

For now you count the amount of uis with `btn <- sum(input$insertBtn, 1)`. Therefore, the rows are numbered by the amount of units ever being added, not the amount of visible rows. So if a user adds 2 rows, deletes them and adds another one, there will be row 1 and row 4.

In case this is not desired one could attempt placing the counting mechanism in a global reactive variable.

- Removing the inputs on server side

For now you cleaned up the ui side. But the inputs will still be available on the server side. In case this should be cleaned up as well, there is an example on how to do so here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-add-removing-modules-dynamically/.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)


LHSchoices <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")

LHSchoices2 <- c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE UI ----
variablesUI <- function(id, number) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    div(id = id,
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
               selectInput(ns("variable"),
                           paste0("Select Variable ", number),
                           choices = c("Choose" = "", LHSchoices)
               )
        ),

        column(3,
               numericInput(ns("value.variable"),
                            label = paste0("Value ", number),
                            value = 0, min = 0
               )
        ),
        column(3,
               actionButton(ns("rmvv"),"Remove UI")
        ),
      )
    )
  )

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# MODULE SERVER ----

variables <- function(input, output, session, variable.number){
  reactive({

    req(input$variable, input$value.variable)

    # Create Pair: variable and its value
    df <- data.frame(
      "variable.number" = variable.number,
      "variable" = input$variable,
      "value" = input$value.variable,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    return(df)

  })
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Shiny UI ----

ui <- fixedPage(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",id="tabs",
              tabPanel("t1",value="t1"),
              tabPanel("t2",value="t2")),

  variablesUI("var1", 1),
  h5(""),
  actionButton("insertBtn", "Add another line"),

  verbatimTextOutput("test1"),
  tableOutput("test2"),

  actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
  textInput("txt", "This is no longer useful")
)

# Shiny Server ----

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # this remove button works, from https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/removeUI.html
  observeEvent(input$rmv, {
    removeUI(
      selector = "div:has(> #txt)"
    )
  })

  add.variable <- reactiveValues()

  add.variable$df <- data.frame("variable.number" = numeric(0),
                                "variable" = character(0),
                                "value" = numeric(0),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  var1 <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", 1), 1)

  observe(add.variable$df[1, ] <- var1())

  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {

    btn <- sum(input$insertBtn, 1)

    insertUI(
      selector = "h5",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tagList(
        variablesUI(paste0("var", btn), btn)
      )
    )

    newline <- callModule(variables, paste0("var", btn), btn)

    observeEvent(newline(), {
      add.variable$df[btn, ] <- newline()
    })

    observeEvent(input[[paste0("var", btn,"-rmvv")]], {
      removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#var", btn)
      )
    })


  })

  output$test1 <- renderPrint({
    print(add.variable$df)
  })

  output$test2 <- renderTable({
    add.variable$df
  })

}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works perfectly. and I didn't mention: the output data frame should also be updated. I am working on it.

Comment: I have also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225295/shiny-updateselectinput-for-a-module-ui) to update selectInput. Would mind have a look ?

Comment: If you could enhence the code, it would be very nice of you.

Comment: You mean all three of the suggested enhancements?

Comment: I was talking about: cleaning the output dataframe and updating selectinput. and for the first one, I add `add.variable$df<- add.variable$df[-btn, ]` just after `removeUI` and then I print `add.variable$df[is.na(add.variable$df$variable)==F,]`. Maybe not the best strategy, but it works. And I am still struggling to understand `updateSelectInput`...

Comment: Hi Tonio, thank you again for your help. Now I would like to add a **new button**, a button that could delete all added UI objects. How would you do it ? Thank you

Comment: I am stuck at the beginning because I didn't really understand why "removeUI" is in "observeEvent" of "input$insertBtn". But so be it. So if now I have to delete **all** added UI objects, do I have to stay in "observeEvent" of "input$insertBtn", even though the action to deleted all added UI objects is should not be dependant of the "insertBtn".

Comment: Hi Xiaoshi, thats an interesting question. I think its beyond the scope of the current question. Would you mind posting a new one? I am happy to take a look!

Comment: Thank you Tonio, I found an interesting post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762013/how-can-i-refer-an-action-button-to-an-inserted-plot-insertui-removeui-in-shin I will first to try do something..

Comment: Hello Tonio, I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475642/shiny-insert-remove-ui-individually-and-globally Could you please have a look. Thank you

Comment: I also would be very interested in creating a global counter. For my case, it would not be necessary to reindex the variables every time one UI is deleted. But it could be useful when all UI are deleted, then we restart at 1.